# Google Cloud Datastore on App Engine with Java. Which package to use?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Newbie to Datastore. I found two tutorials on the GCP site to use Datastore on App Engine. Which one should I use?

There are subtle differences in how the APIs work.

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/datastore-api-tutorial
uses package (import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;)

vs.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/building-app/cloud-datastore
uses package (import com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity)

Question: Is there a preferred package to use and call the datastore API while on App Engine - com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity vs. com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity?

Comment: Ok.. now when there are clearly 2 different ways of doing the same thing , why would one down vote the question when I ask which is a better way to do things ?

Comment: I have noticed a performance difference between the two. Low Level AppEngine DataStore library is faster on AppEngine compared to the more generic DataStore Client Library running on AppEngine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library with this package `com.google.appengine.api.datastore` (aka "Datastore API for Java") is intended for use by Java 7 and Java 8 applications which run on AppEngine.

The library with this package `com.google.cloud.datastore` (aka "Cloud Datastore client library") is intended for use by any Java 8 application regardless of where it is deployed (GKE, GCE, on-premises etc)

From [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/#connecting_to_datastore_name_short_with_app_engine):

> **Datastore API for Java** is a low-level Datastore API built into the App Engine SDK to provide direct access to all Datastore features and is described throughout the App Engine Datastore documentation for Java.
>
> **Cloud Datastore client library** is a library that can be used by apps in the App Engine standard Java 8 runtime, by applications in the App Engine flexible environment, and by non App Engine applications as well.

So, according to Google, both are valid choices subject to these limitations ...

- If you are running Java 7 then you cannot use Cloud Datastore client library
- If your application is not deployed to AppEngine then you cannot use Datastore API for Java

These limitations describe the scenarios in which one or other of these libraries *cannot* be used. Google offers no advice on which one *should* be used. This is because the two libraries are functionally equivalent so, assuming that the limitations described above do not apply to your usage, the choice is probably moot.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I will stick with the client library for now. The differences were minor in terms of how we create an entity, the constructors available etc.